# R.id android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem with android studio 0.4. There is and error with r.id. I think i messes something with the imports or activity_main.xml up because there is an error in main_xml, too. And when I hover over R.id, android studio whants me to write android.R.id.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

lblTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblTest);
```

activity_main.xml (table marked red)

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnDice"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="table">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="false"
            android:id="@+id/btnFalse"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_below="table"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="true"
            android:id="@+id/btnTrue"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_below="table"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

error messages:

String types not allowed (at 'layout_below' with value 'table').

Cannot resolve method 'setContentView(?)'. Cannot resolve symbol 'R'.

any ideas?

Comment: import <your.package.name>.R;

Comment: Check if you have same errors.On the top left, click on "project" combo. You can find an entry "problems".

Comment: I solved the problem myself. I think `R` was connected to the wrong library. Just hover over `R` and click more. Then try tick try change the library, done :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you have an error in your XML.  Sounds like you are trying to set a String attribute for a 'layout' parameter, when this should actually be a reference to another element in your layout.

Bottom line, check your layout.xml for a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks! I just forgot to write `@+id/` infront of the id. But the `R` of `R.id` is still marked red.

Answer (score 0):

You should always post your error for us to see, otherwise it's much harder to help you.

I think your error is very simple.

Just go to your main activity, where the java code is and press and hold `Shift` `Ctrl` `O`

`Shift Ctrl O`

Comment: Shift Ctrl O doesn't do anything :(

Answer (score 0):

When you are using this code : `findViewById(R.id.anything);` you must import `android.R.id`. use this and if you have error again please write it for us.

Comment: @keyboardlizard : if you are using eclipse delete gen folder and let eclipse auto generate it.

Answer (score 0):

If all or a majority of the R's are appearing as errors, go to build and clean project. Now the errors should have disappeared or you should be able to import the R's to your activity.